# ZSH prompt not showing git unstaged files

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

I'm using vcs_info to add information about git to my prompt. I have configured:

```
setopt promptsubst                
autoload -Uz vcs_info             
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git   
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' stagedstr '!'
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' unstagedstr '?'                                           
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats '[%b]%c%u'
...
PROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}$ '
```

Now, I have a git repo with current changes, namely a staged and unstaged file:

```
# On branch test
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   a
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       b
```

However, my prompt is ignoring the unstaged file and just showing ! for the staged one. It looks as follows:

```
[test]!$
```

Either I misunderstood what %u should output or I must have a typo somewhere. I'm on zsh 4.3.17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your .zshrc is probably OK.

Your repository's file "a" is staged. So zsh shows "!" in prompt for it as expected. But file "b" is only untracked. Untracked != unstaged. Therefore, "?" is not shown.

Comment: I think you totally misunderstood my question. I just want to know why my zsh is not showing ? even if there are unstaged files.

Comment: Your repository's file a is staged. so shows "!" in prompt. this is OK. But file b is Untracked. Untracked != Unstaged. so not shows "?".

Comment: Ok, I see where you are heading to. I misinterpreted what vcs_info will give me in case of untracked files. So basically it is missing a placeholder for untracked files :-) I will edit your answer and accept it.